# how to upgrade to android studio 1.0?

Tags: java, android, ide, android-studio, upgrade

Guys i am running on android studo 8.X , now google has released 1.0? (no more in beta), when i try updating the updater just redirects me to the download page, how can i set it up without ,you know messing up anything else, i have a lot of system images , lollipop ,android wear mage etc set up in the sdk manager ,now will the new install wipe off all that , is there and what is the safest way to upgrade?

Please note i'm a newbie developer and i don't know much about these tools and IDE's .

Comment: NOTE: i  have to ask here because its relatively new and i couldnt find other resources regarding my question

Answer (score 2):

It redirects you to the download page because between 0.8.0 and 1.0 there were some releases that didn't allow update via patches, the only thing you could do is download the whole fresh version.
When you install new version of Android Studio, it asks you about previous installations. If you had AS installed (which is obviously your case) you can import its settings during the installation of 1.0.
You can also point your AS 1.0 to your SDK path, no need to download all these libraries again.